# Access 2003 Nested Selects itche

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, query-optimization, ms-access-2003

I've a query that looks like:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT Attribute FROM TableOfAttributes WHERE KeyField = MyTable.KeyField AND Type = "A") AS Attribute1,
       (SELECT Attribute FROM TableOfAttributes WHERE KeyField = MyTable.KeyField AND Type = "B") AS Attribute2,
       (SELECT Attribute FROM TableOfAttributes WHERE KeyField = MyTable.KeyField AND Type = "C") AS Attribute3
FROM
       MyTable
```

Indeed ! In MyTable information is horizontal, but in TableOfAttributes it's vertical, I'm trying to figure out how to rip off these nested queries because currently this is taking too long to execute (more than an hour).

To sum up in words: I've a table with entries, every entry has attributes in another table, every attribute is stored in one record and an entry has 3 attributes.

I want to show up:

```
[Entry ID] [Entry Something] [Attribute1] [Attribute2] [Attribute3]
```

How would you guys solve that ?

Thanks in advance

Miloud B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just join the table using an alias for each table.  If there are instances where there doesn't exist a match in one of the Att tables, you'll need an outer join.

```
SELECT m.*, Att1.Attribute, Att2.Attribute, Att3.Attribute 
FROM MyTable m, TableOfAttributes Att1, TableOfAttributes Att2, TableOfAttributes Att3 
WHERE Att1.KeyField = m.KeyField AND Type = "A" 
and Att2.KeyField = m.KeyField AND Type = "B"
and Att3.KeyField = m.KeyField AND Type = "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do just one `JOIN` with your `TableOfAttribute` table, and perform a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT  [Entry ID], [Entry Something], 
        MIN(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'A' THEN Attribute ELSE NULL END) AS Attribute1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'B' THEN Attribute ELSE NULL END) AS Attribute2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'C' THEN Attribute ELSE NULL END) AS Attribute3
FROM MyTable 
LEFT JOIN TableOfAttributes
ON MyTable.KeyField = TableOfAttributes.KeyField
GROUP BY [Entry ID], [Entry Something]
```

Comment: Thank you ! John's way works, but I think I'll need yours to easily included nulls using an outer join instead ! Thank you man.

By the way, Access has IIF but no CASE WHEN statement ;)

Comment: Oh, right, forgot about the iif. Well, you got the idea, at least ;)